# "Scraping" the letters directly after a href link

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I recently started with Python and I'm  trying to code my own WebCrawler / Scraper to learn the language a little bit more. The problem I have is (part of the HTML):

```
<td class="name"><a href="/leagues/euw/1234">THENAME</a></td>
                                                ^
                                           I want the name
```

When I run my application I only get the output of:
for ex.: `<td class="name"><a href="/leagues/euw/1234">THENAME</a></td>`

And as a "Beginner" I don't know how I can get THENAME out there with Python.

This is my Python code already:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def summ_spider(max_pages):
    page = 5000
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = "http://www.lolsummoners.com/ladders/euw/" + str(page)
        r = requests.get(url)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
#       print (soup)

        links = soup.find_all("a")

        for link in links:
            print
            "<a href='{0:s}'>{1:s}</a>".format(link.get("href"), link.text)


        g_data = soup.find_all("table", {"class": "ladder"})
        n_data = soup.find_all("td", {"class": "name"})

        page+=1

        f_data = n_data [108:122]

        print(f_data)
#       print (links)
#       print (n_data)

summ_spider(3000000)
```

PS: I would like to have the output (will do a .txt safe later) 
only:

```
NAME1
NAME2
NAME3
```

and not the other HTML around. 
I would be very thankful for some help / critism

Comment: The line after the singular `print` does the trick already. But it does not return it. Print that string or just `link.text` to see what you want to see.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for the answer. But when I print it out I only get "Next"

Comment: Then there might be a link "Next" on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your function you get a response like `<td class="name"><a href="/leagues/euw/1234">THENAME</a></td>` because that's what you're actually printing. If you want to get the "name" of the link you can do something like

```
for link in links:
    print link.text
```

The reason you got "Next" returned is because that's the last link on the page.

Comment: Wow that did the trick! Thanks so much for your help and Klaus.D aswell :)  Can I do that the word "Next" for example is some kind of blacklisted so it is never shown?

Comment: Didn't know how I could do it. Got it now! ^^